# linux perf record: difference between count (-c) and frequency (-F) options

Tags: linux, count, frequency, perf

I'm trying to understand what the -c and -F options of **perf record** really do but I cannot explain what I'm seeing. I'm running these commands:

```
perf record -a -F <frequency> sleep 1
```

and

```
perf record -a -c <count> sleep 1
```

trying different values of *frequency* and *count*. The results I get are
[the following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7gYf.png)

In the first table I set the frequency and in the second one the count. How do frequency and count affect the number of events? I thought the number of events was independent on the frequency and count, but clearly it's not the case. What does perf actually do?

Comment: How did you get "samples" and "events" in your table?

Comment: It is very likely obtained with the help of `perf report`.

Comment: Yes, I used perf report

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`Count` and `frequency` are two fundamental switches that tune the rate of sampling when using `perf record` (which does sampling internally).

**Count**

When you run `perf record -c <number>`, you are specifying the sample period (where "number" is the sample period). That is, for every "number"th occurrence of the event a sample will be recorded. The sample will be recorded when the performance counter that keeps track of the number of events has overflowed.

I am guessing you are obtaining the number of events with the help of `perf report`. Note that `perf report` will never report the actual number of events, but only an approximate. The number of events will keep changing as you keep tweaking the sample period. `perf report` will only read the `perf.data` file that `perf record` generates, and based on the size of the file generated, it makes an assumption of the number of samples recorded (by knowing the size of a sample recorded in memory). The actual number of events recorded is obtained by -

`Number of events = Fixed Sample Period * Number of samples collected`

where Fixed Sample Period is what you specified with `perf record -c`.

**Frequency**

This is the other way around to express the sampling period, that is to specify the average rate of samples per second (frequency) - which you can do using perf record -F. So `perf record -F 1000` will record around 1000 samples per second and these samples will be generated when the hardware/PMU counter corresponding to the event overflows. This means that the kernel will dynamically adjust the sampling period to make sure that the `sampling` process adheres to the sampling frequency.

[This](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.4/source/kernel/events/core.c#L7724) is how the sample period gets updated dynamically.

Higher the sampling frequency, higher the number of samples collected (almost proportionately).

The variation in the sampling period can be seen by running the command -

`sudo perf report -D -i perf.data | fgrep RECORD_SAMPLE`

Whenever the sampling period keeps varying, the total number of events will keep incrementing with the variation in the sampling period. And when the sampling period remains fixed, the total number of events remain fixed and is obtained by the formula showed above. The total number of events will be approximate in both the cases.

Comment: What you explained is correct but doesn't explain the results I obtained. What I expect to see with the -F option is that the number of samples is directly proportional to the frequency and #samples/frequency is the total runtime of the program. The number of events should be constant. With the -c option count x samples should be very close to the number of events seen with the -F option. In order to reproduce this I had to pass an event (-e cycles for instance) and use a value of count *high enough*. I think perf uses a min value if you pass a very small number, without telling you

Comment: Hi @Arnabjyoti Kalita , your explanation is great. But do you know why when the system is relatively idle, the number of samples perf collects is not correct. For example, I run sampling with 100HZ and run it for 10 second. I expect it to have 1000 samples, but in fact I can only get 200. Any thoughts on this? I am really confused by this problem. (when the system is fully loaded, it can get around 1000 samples) Thanks!
I am using this cmd: `sudo perf record -F 100 -a -g -- sleep 10;`

Comment: @RichardLi Don't make the frequency divided by system ticker frequency, usually 100Hz for linux. See  http://www.brendangregg.com/perf.html

Comment: With a multithreaded program, is the sampling rate estimated separately for all threads, or globally?

Comment: @nnnmmm, it depends on how you ask the userspace program to do sampling. Sampling can be done per-process, per-thread or for the entire system.

Comment: This explanation doesn't match the data I see at all. When I use `-F` then `RECORD_SAMPLE` still shows a single consistent period value for the entire run. When I use `-c` I see it respects the value I picked for the period, but `event_count*samples` differs wildly based on my choice for `-c`. Paradoxically small values for `-c` result in **fewer** samples, which makes no sense. Wat. This is testing with `idq_uops_not_delivered.core`.