# Interpreting perf script columns

Tags: perf

For the following `perf` record command

```
perf record -e cycles:k -j any,k -a
```

I see the following columns when I read it via `perf script`

```
       nginx 12722 60659.641815:          1 cycles:k:  ffffffffa2a72f36 native_write_msr+0x6 (/lib/modules/4.19.119/build/vmlinux
       nginx 12722 60659.641828:          1 cycles:k:  ffffffffa2a72f36 native_write_msr+0x6 (/lib/modules/4.19.119/build/vmlinux
       nginx 12722 60659.641835:          3 cycles:k:  ffffffffa2a72f36 native_write_msr+0x6 (/lib/modules/4.19.119/build/vmlinux
       nginx 12722 60659.641842:         17 cycles:k:  ffffffffa2a72f36 native_write_msr+0x6 (/lib/modules/4.19.119/build/vmlinux
       nginx 12722 60659.641848:         97 cycles:k:  ffffffffa2a72f36 native_write_msr+0x6 (/lib/modules/4.19.119/build/vmlinux
       nginx 12722 60659.641855:        547 cycles:k:  ffffffffa2a72f36 native_write_msr+0x6 (/lib/modules/4.19.119/build/vmlinux
       nginx 12722 60659.641861:       3060 cycles:k:  ffffffffa2a72f36 native_write_msr+0x6 (/lib/modules/4.19.119/build/vmlinux
       nginx 12722 60659.641868:      17723 cycles:k:  ffffffffa2a72f36 native_write_msr+0x6 (/lib/modules/4.19.119/build/vmlinux
       nginx 12722 60659.641884:      99057 cycles:k:  ffffffffa2bbdaba irq_work_run_list+0xa (/lib/modules/4.19.119/build/vmlinu
       nginx 12722 60659.641939:     274693 cycles:k:  ffffffffa329ade4 sock_poll+0x44 (/lib/modules/4.19.119/build/vmlinux)
       nginx 12722 60659.642112:     397008 cycles:k:  ffffffffa333cc7b tcp_write_xmit+0xbb (/lib/modules/4.19.119/build/vmlinux)
```

I know that 12722 is the PID. I would like to know what are "60659.641815" and "1 cycles" columns? I guess the former is the time but don't know why it starts from 60659.641815.

Answer (score 4):

You are right, "60659.641815" is representing `timestamp` in the units of `seconds.microseconds`. This timestamp represents the number of seconds since the system was started. For more details, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61428513).

`cycles:k` represents the event name and the value 1 is not associated with `cycles`. These values 1,3,17,97, 547 etc. represent the sample period. This means, if you have a sample period of x, at the xth occurence of the event, the hardware counter corresponding to the `cycles` event overflowed and a sample was written.

A quick and easy check to verify the above statement is to run `perf record` with a fixed sample period of, say 2, and then see `perf script` output,

```
perf record -e cycles:k -j any,k -c 2 -a
^C[ perf record: Woken up 1 times to write data ]
[ perf record: Captured and wrote 1.289 MB perf.data (8 samples) ]


perf script

            perf  5746 [000] 54322.047321:          2 cycles:k:  ffffffffb786ee9a native_write_msr+0xa ([kernel.kallsyms])
         swapper     0 [001] 54322.047350:          2 cycles:k:  ffffffffb786ee9a native_write_msr+0xa ([kernel.kallsyms])
         swapper     0 [002] 54322.047425:          2 cycles:k:  ffffffffb786ee9a native_write_msr+0xa ([kernel.kallsyms])
         swapper     0 [003] 54322.047449:          2 cycles:k:  ffffffffb786ee9a native_write_msr+0xa ([kernel.kallsyms])
         swapper     0 [004] 54322.047473:          2 cycles:k:  ffffffffb786ee9a native_write_msr+0xa ([kernel.kallsyms])
         swapper     0 [005] 54322.047496:          2 cycles:k:  ffffffffb786ee9a native_write_msr+0xa ([kernel.kallsyms])
         swapper     0 [006] 54322.047519:          2 cycles:k:  ffffffffb786ee9a native_write_msr+0xa ([kernel.kallsyms])
 MediaPl~back #3  2095 [007] 54322.047545:          2 cycles:k:  ffffffffb786ee9a native_write_msr+0xa ([kernel.kallsyms])
```

Comment: What is the point with seeing the sample period then? If you look at my output, the last line 397008. I have to say that other rows after that are also around 397K-398K. What is the point with seeing large or small values?

Comment: So, unless you specify a fixed sample period to collect samples, the `kernel` will collect samples at 'arbitrary' periods. The kernel keeps tuning this sample period, so as to make sure that most of the time is not spent collecting these samples. You can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53455058).